# Foreign key fields different databases. Django

Tags: django, django-models

Is that possible to have model with foreign key fields on different databases?
example:

```
class MultiBDModel(models.Model):
    db1_user = models.ForeignKey(User) # here suppose to be foreign key on `db1`
    db2_user = models.ForeignKey(User) # and here on `db2`
```

maybe copy somehow User. Apply for it custom manager. Which returns query set with using='db1'

in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'db1',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    },

    'website': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'db2',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.              # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The ORM cannot do anything the database engine isn't capable of.

Comment: Ok i understood. I forget that django is doing joins in database not in python.

Answer (score 2):

No. As written by @ignacio-vazquez-abrams, one model must have all fields in the same database.

---

### BUT

As an alternative, you could use a proxy model to link between models from two different databases.

### Aim

One model should provide the fields from db1 and db2 at the same time

### General trick

- You have the model `ContactMessage` from db1, that we will name `legacy_db`. We suppose you don't want to touch to this model since it comes from another project.
- Create a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) `ProxyContactMessage`, it has the same attributes than `ContactMessage`.
- Use a [database router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653449/django-database-router#12548439) to tell Django where to look in `legacy_db` for `ProxyContactMessage` objects.
- Add a new model `ExtendedContactMessage` with the fields you would like to add. Declare a `OneToOneField` with `ProxyContactMessage`. This data will be saved to your db2 `django_db`.
- Your proxy model cannot hold the new fields since it's abstract, but it can have methods that ask the related `ExtendedContactMessage` object (if any). Add the callables you want.

### Example

In your `legacy_app/models.py`, the model on db1 `legacy_db` is:

```
class ContactMessage(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    message = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'contact_message'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.subject
```

Therefore you create in `myapp/models.py`:

```
class ProxyContactMessage(ContactMessage):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = 'Contact message'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Contact messages'

    def add_extension(self):
        e = ExtendedContactMessage(contact_message=self)
        e.save()
        return e

    def mark_as_processed(self):
        try:
            e = self.extendedcontactmessage
        except ExtendedContactMessage.DoesNotExist:
            e = self.add_extension()
        e.mark_as_processed()

    def processed(self):
        return self.extendedcontactmessage.processed

    def processed_at(self):
        return self.extendedcontactmessage.processed_at

class ExtendedContactMessage(models.Model):
    contact_message = models.OneToOneField(ProxyContactMessage)
    processed = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
    processed_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None, editable=False)

    def mark_as_processed(self):
        self.processed = True
        self.processed_at = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

Note that only the non abstract model `ExtendedContactMessage` will be saved in db2, since `ProxyContactMessage` is abstract.

In `settings.py`, set DATABASE_ROUTERS with the class

```
class LegacyRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    legacy database.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model.__name__ == 'ProxyContactMessage':
            return 'legacy_db'
        return None
    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write in legacy DB for ContactMessage.
        """
        if model.__name__ == 'ProxyContactMessage':
            return 'legacy_db'
        return None
```

Your default router sends everything to db2.

Finally you may have an admin class like:

```
def mark_as_processed(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for obj in queryset:
        obj.mark_as_processed()
mark_as_processed.short_description = "Mark as processed"

class ProxyContactMessageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'subject',
        'message',
        'created_at',
        'created_by',
        'processed',
        'processed_at',
    )
    actions = (mark_as_processed,)
admin.site.register(ProxyContactMessage, ProxyContactMessageAdmin)
```

---

Related:

[Use a router for the proxy class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41638954/5033681)

["Hack" the app_name in Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41930531/5033681)

[Catch the queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4650544/5033681)