# Django proxy model to different database

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, proxy-classes

## Situation

---

We have a few different applications which use tickets from a ticket support system for different kinds of functionality.

First of all we have an application which has a few models that represent the models of our ticket support system Kayako. This application should not know anything about other applications that make use of it and should remain as generic as possible. Since this application is using existing tables of Kayako we have it running on the same database. Let's call this application `kayakodb`.

One application links customers from our customer database to tickets in the ticket support system. Previously this system had it's own representation of the tickets inside our ticket support system, querying for tickets by using an API provided by `kayakodb`. It then used this representation of tickets to link customers and domains to. This however was too complex and not very logical. So we opted to switch it to a proxy model and move the models that represent the links to customers and domains to `kayakodb`. Let's call this application `sidebar`.

Another, new application, shows the tickets from the ticket support system in a clear overview alongside calls so our support department can easily see which calls and tickets are related to which customers. This system has a proxy model to the proxy model of `sidebar`, because some of the functionality provided by the `sidebar` model are also required for this application alongside some others which the new proxy model declare. Let's call this project `WOW`.

The `sidebar` and `WOW` applications are both part of the same project/repository. We'll call this repository `Coneybeach` which has its own database. However, `kayakodb` is a completely unrelated project. It is included in `Coneybeach` via a requirements file which we install via `pip`.

## Problem

---

When creating migrations for the new setup Django creates a proxy model migration for the installed `kayakodb` which is, of course, a no go. Any time we would install a new version of `kayakodb` it would overwrite this migration. Let alone the fact that `kayakodb` shouldn't know anything about which models make use of it.

## Code

---

The `Ticket` model inside `kayakodb`:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    """
    This model is a representation of the data stored in the "kayako" database table "swtickets". Minus a lot of stuff
    we don't use. If you add a field make sure it has the same name as the field in kayako.swtickets.
    """
    # Fields, functions and manager etc.

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'swtickets'
        managed = False
```

The `SidebarTicket` proxy model inside `sidebar`:

```
from kayakodb.models import Ticket    

class SidebarTicket(Ticket):
    class Meta:
        # Since this class is a wrapper we don't want to create a table for it. We only want to access the original
        # model as we always do, but provide a different interface (when it comes to functions). Proxy models allow us
        # to do this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#proxy-models
        proxy = True

        # Don't look for this model in the sidebar tables, but in the kayakodb tables.
        app_label = 'kayakodb'

    # Some extra functions
```

The `Contact` class `TicketWrapper` inherits from (as requested by Hynekcer). This model is used as base model for `TicketWrapper` and another model representing calls (though there are not issues with this model as far as I'm aware):

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    type = None

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in ['customers', 'add_customer_id', 'remove_all_customers', 'byters', 'domainnames', 'add_domain_name',
                    'remove_domain_name', 'add_text', 'remove_text', 'texts', 'creation_date', 'add_tag', 'get_tags',
                    'remove_tag', 'identifier']:
            raise NotImplementedError('You should implement {}'.format(attr))
        raise AttributeError(attr)
```

The `TicketWrapper` proxy model inside `WOW`:

```
from sidebar.models import SidebarTicket

class TicketWrapper(Contact, SidebarTicket):
    class Meta:
        # Since this class is a wrapper we don't want to create a table for it. We only want to access the original
        # model as we always do, but provide a different interface (when it comes to functions). Proxy models allow us
        # to do this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#proxy-models
        proxy = True

        # Don't look for this model in the WOW database, but in the kayakodb database.
        app_label = 'kayakodb'

    # Some extra functions
```

## What have I tried

---

- I've tried not specifying the `app_label` for both the proxy models. This creates correct migrations, but causes the proxy models to look for the `kayakodb.Ticket` model in the Coneybeach database.
- I've tried specifying `abstract = True` for the subclasses, but wasn't sure this was the because I still want to be able to make use of the manager for the models.
- I considered moving the migration that gets created currently to the actual `kayakodb` project, but I don't think this is a good solution. `kayakodb` shouldn't know anything about the implementations of its models or where they are used.
- `./manage.py check` returns 0 issues.

## Question

---

How can I create a proxy model for a model that's located in a different database or project?

## Edit

---

After setting the `kayakodb.Ticket` model to be unmanaged the `WOW` project tries to create a migration for *all* models in `kayakodb`. Result:

```
Migrations for 'sidebar':
  0004_auto_20170116_1210.py:
    - Delete model Ticket

Migrations for 'kayakodb':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Staff
    - Create model Tag
    - Create model Ticket
    - Create model TicketPost
    - Create model TicketTag
    - Create model TicketCustomer
    - Create model TicketDomain
    - Create proxy model SidebarTicket
    - Alter unique_together for ticketdomain (1 constraint(s))
    - Alter unique_together for ticketcustomer (1 constraint(s))
    - Create proxy model TicketWrapper
```

Comment: @e4c5 Yes I know that. That's nice and all, but if it _is_ of consequence when it is overwritten.

Comment: You say so yourself "That's because the proxy model maybe referred by another model in a future migration." Why would it otherwise bother creating a migration if it can be just thrown away afterwards?

Comment: You got me there!! Retracting close vote.

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks :) No hard feelings ;)

Comment: not at all. Here is a +1 from me

Comment: Please, explain which models should be represented by tables. The names KayakoTicket and Contact are currently undefined. The model TickedWrapper does not create a relationship between Contact and SidebarTicket because it is an invalid proxy (without data). Primary problem is a correct database model that pass the check `python manage.py check`. Secondary important problem is how much databases are used and correct db routers for them.

Comment: @hynekcer Ah my bad `KayakoTicket` is just `kayakodb.Ticket`, but imported with an `as` statement. I'll add the definition of the `Contact` class. The only models that should have tables representing them are the models in the `kayakodb` project. FYI, `./manage.py check` returns 0 errors or warnings (Django 1.9.10).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @hynekcer said if `kayakodb` is an existing database, you need to set `managed = False` for all its models.
However, that still leaves the problem of the migration for the proxy model created inside the wrong app (`kayakodb`).

The hacky fix that might work is changing the `app_label` of the proxy model to whatever app is okay to put the migration to (`sidebar` in this case), and making a router that will point this proxy model to read and write from `kayakodb`.

E.g. the proxy model:

```
# in sidebar/models.py

class SidebarTicket(KayakoTicket):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = 'sidebar'
```

and the router inside the project that uses it:

```
from django.conf import settings
from kayakodb.models import Ticket

class ProxyDatabaseRouter(object):
    def allow_proxy_to_different_db(self, obj_):
        # check if this is a sidebar proxy to the Ticket model in kayakodb
        return isinstance(obj_, Ticket) and obj_._meta.proxy and obj_._meta.app_label == 'sidebar'

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if issubclass(model, Ticket) and model._meta.proxy and model._meta.app_label == 'sidebar':
            return 'kayakodb'
        # the rest of the method goes here

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if issubclass(model, Ticket) and model._meta.proxy and model._meta.app_label == 'sidebar':
            return 'kayakodb'
        return None
        # the rest of the method goes here

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if self.allow_proxy_to_different_db(obj1) or self.allow_proxy_to_different_db(obj2):
            return True
        # the rest of the method goes here
```

Comment: It is useful, but the condition `if model == SidebarTicket:` is still invalid, because SidebarTicket is only a proxy, but the database model is not described enough yet and the correct condition is therefore not known.

Comment: @hynekcer as I said, how exactly the comparison is done is not important, consider the above half pseudocode. 

The DB for read and write can even be stored in the model itself, allowing router methods return `getattr(model, "_CUSTOM_DATABASE", None)` if need be, which is not a problem since model is passed along into the router methods.

Comment: updated the router code snippet with better if clauses and the `allow_relation` method that was missing

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr but I grepped your question for a word `router` which is not mentioned, so I'd think the thing you are looking for are [Database Routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-routing)

Comment: If the question is  "How can I create a proxy model for a model that's located in a different database or project", the answer could be "use database router". Sorry for trying to help.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to be rude. I do apologize. Writing to the model in the different database is not the problem (for me in any case). The problem is that a migration is created in the wrong place (and if you read the question, you would have seen this :)). Tell you what, if you edit your question to include more information about the DB routers (provide an example). I'll be able to remove my down vote. Looking purely at the question itself I do agree that this _could_ have been the answer.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr  Use

```
class Meta:
    managed = False
```

for all models in the db that should not be controlled by Django. (i.e. kayakodb)

---

It should be noted that PyPI `Kayako` is a Python API (without Djago) to some Kayako app written in another language.

It is usefull to know from you that Kayako and WOW are in different databases but it is not a fundamantal information. Django allows e.g. that one model is present in two databases: a primary and a secondary db. The most important are meta options, the option `managed = False` in this case. It is for the case [Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/legacy-databases/). That does not mean only exactly a very old project, but a project that is not written in Python+Django or does not support migrations and does not share information which migrations are not applied yet. Maybe if a new version of Kayako would add a new fields to database, you don need to read that field or if you add it to the model, Django is not responsible to add the field to database because it is controlled by Kayako upgrade.

You can alternatively use database routers to create no tables for kayakodb app (nowhere) and also no tables in kayakodb database e.g. for Django users and groups:

file **myrouter.py** or similar

```
class MyRouter(object):
    allow_migrate(db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'kayakodb' or db == 'kayakodb':
            return False
```

file **settings.py**

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.myrouter.MyRouter',...]
# ... if another router has been defined previously
```

The advantage is that this disables migration for any current or future model, but I recommend to add a text `class Meta: managed = False` also somewhere to comments in `kayakodb/models.py` in order to make it clear to any later developer, because he can easily forget to read the routers first.

You can write a dependency of your project versions on a minimal and maximal version of Kayako API, but it can not be in form of migration.

---

Your another problem is that "[A proxy model must inherit **from exactly one** non-abstract model class...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#s-base-class-restrictions).", but your proxy model `TicketWrapper` inherits from`Contact` and `SidebarTicket`. It looks like a nonsense and I'm wondering that you don't see an error `TypeError: Proxy model 'TicketWrapper' has more than one non-abstract model base class.` The same Contact can be shared by more tickets. (Is not it a registered user? Can not he change anything in his user profile during the history of issue?) It should be probably a foreign key to Contact, not a multiple inheritance.

Comment: `Contact` is an abstract Django model in this case, so that's alright. I've set the `managed = False` for the `kayakodb` models. But when I try to create a migration in the `WOW` project now it tries to create a migration for all `kayakodb` models (even though they're unmanaged). When setting the router to not allow migrations for `kayakodb` models that works, but this also means the proxy model migration is not created, which I require (AFAIA). So I'm still running into the problem that I can't create a proxy model (or a migration for one) for the models specified in kayakodb.